# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (11,) while executing plot_diagnostics function

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, jupyter-notebook, prediction, forecasting

```
   results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(12,12))
   plt.show()
```

**On executing this code gives the error:**

```
    ValueError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-81-043aced67484> in <module>
----> 1 results.plot_diagnostics(figsize=(12,12))
      2 plt.show()

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py in 
 plot_diagnostics(self, variable, lags, fig, figsize)
  2631         ax = fig.add_subplot(224)
  2632         from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
-> 2633         plot_acf(resid, ax=ax, lags=lags)
   2634         ax.set_title('Correlogram')
   2635 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\graphics\tsaplots.py in 
  plot_acf(x, 
 ax, lags, alpha, use_vlines, unbiased, fft, title, zero, vlines_kwargs, 
 **kwargs)
   132     else:
 133         acf_x, confint = acf(x, nlags=nlags, alpha=alpha, fft=fft,
--> 134                              unbiased=unbiased)
  135 
  136     _plot_corr(ax, title, acf_x, confint, lags, irregular, use_vlines,

  ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\stattools.py in acf(x, unbiased, nlags, qstat, fft, alpha, missing)
  483         varacf[2:] *= 1 + 2 * np.cumsum(acf[1:-1]**2)
  484         interval = stats.norm.ppf(1 - alpha / 2.) * np.sqrt(varacf)
 --> 485         confint = np.array(lzip(acf - interval, acf + interval))
   486         if not qstat:
487             return acf, confint
```

On running this code gives the error below:

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (11,)

How can I fix it?

Comment: How many data points do you have in your time series? I also encountered this error and noticed that the lags=10 parameter has a default value of 10. If you have less than 10 data points, you will have a shape error. Reduce the number of lags to match the number of your data points.